# Converting structure of data table using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert an existing data table (Table 1) in Excel to a new data table (Table 2) using vba. The data represents an activity list and corresponding predecessors and I would like it to be in 2 columns rather than multiple. How do I convert table 1 in to table 2?

```
     Table 1:      Table 2:
A                 A
B   A             B   A
C   B   A         C   B
D                 C   A
E   A   D   C     E   A
                  E   D
                  E   C
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra0UD.png)

[image]

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: How do I turn table 1 in to table 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this (pseudocode):

```
int n = 2  // operator for tracking your row index
for i = 1 to end of rows
    for j = 2 to end of column
        if cell(i,j) == empty
            do nothing
        else
            copy cell(1, i) to new table location (column 6, now n)
            copy cell(j, i) to new table location (column 7, row n)
            n = n+1
        end
    end
end
```

Please note column 6 and column 7 refer to the location of the new table.

Comment: And then you need to add an exception for the case where all cells in a row are empty.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it!Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim n As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

n = 12
For i = 3 To LastRow
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
    End With
    
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If Cells(i, j + 1) = "" Then
            
        Else
            Cells(n, 2) = Cells(i, 1)
            Cells(n, 3) = Cells(i, j + 1)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Comment: This writes the answer to a table below on the same sheet